# Cloud code: do we need to escape parameters when we pass them to a query?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a cloud code function that accepts several parameters, do I manually need to escape them or is this handled internally?

If so, are there functions in Parse to do this?

For example:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('like', async (request) =>
{
    const issueID = request.params.issue;
    const q1 = new Parse.Query('Issue');
    // TODO: do we need to escape this issueID?
    q1.equalTo('objectId', issueID);
});
```

Comment: You should be fine with this code.

Comment: can you back this up with some evidence ?

Comment: You can take a look in the official cloud code examples: https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#cloud-functions